# Can't access MySQL via 3G connection

Tags: mysql, linux, networking

I have one strange situation that I need help with...

My Linux machine is connected to internet via 3G connection and it is set up to save collected data to MySQL database that is located on a shared hosting. It's been working like that for a couple of months now without problems and now I'm trying to switch from shared hosting to a new VPS server that I've rented two weeks ago.

On new server I have MySQL installed and working, tried the connection from my desktop machine via Workbench, as well as from my mobile phone. 
When I try the connection on Linux machine - it just won't connect to MySQL (double checked all the parameters). 
I am connecting via IP address on standard TCP 3306 port, I'm sure that port is open on Linux machine because it worked with shared hosting without problems, and on VPS I know is opened because I can connect from my home machine and mobile phone (both on separate networks).

It seems to me that IP address of VPS server can't be accessed from Linux for some reason, but I can't tell why.
Telnet to VPS IP via 3306 port works from my (windows) desktop machine, on Linux I've tried

```
nmap {IP address} -p 3306 -PN
```

and got response:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

Everything seems to be working from other networks except the one on Linux station, and I don't know where to look for the problem. I have also a windows laptop that is connected to the Linux station 3G network and it also does not recognize the VPS IP address (can't telnet to 3306 port), but when I connect laptop to tethered network from my mobile phone - telnet to 3306 works... I'm totally puzzled!

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? Why the VPS can't be accessed via 3G network?
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: witch error message you get from mysql -h IP -u user -p

Comment: i think you need to configure iptables to allow mysql port no. so try to do something like that `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT` then try to nmap scanning again then check it should be opened .

Comment: You need to check the user you connect with if it is allowed to connect from the remote ip (use a wildcard in case of dynamic ip). Also see in my.cnf file. There is a parameter to specify single ip or ranges that can connect. Still in case of dynamic ip on the hosting use 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf. Sorry but I don't remember the name of the param but i am on mobile. Check the file and it should be easy to find anyway

Comment: @BerndBuffen from mysql -h IP -u user -p I get     ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (110)

Comment: @authprivate I tried the command, nmap returns the same result...

Comment: @LelioFaieta User can connect, I've established connection successfully from my desktop machine.

Comment: try to `ps -e | grep mysql` then check if the service is up and running or not .. this mean ur service is not currently running .

Comment: I don't think this is the case since the connection works from other computers/to other server...